# How to write a pivot for this

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following table:

```
+---------+-------+
| unit_id | Code  |
+---------+-------+
|  214825 | D1821 |
|  214825 | D0235 |
|  214825 | D0710 |
+---------+-------+
```

I want a query that does the following:

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| unit_id | code1 | code2 | code3 |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
|  214825 | D1821 | D0235 | D0710 |
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I tried pivot but it requires me to sum the data, is there any other way?

Comment: Is there any other column values that indicate the values from Code should placed to code1 or code2 or code3?

Comment: No, but I know each unit_id has 3 values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number as below to achieve your requirement. This way the code value in three different column will be placed either randomly (if no ordering select while generating row_number) or ascending/descending order you applied (as in my query)-

You can check [DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f869b31cb15c4a738432732358624628)

```
SELECT unit_id, 
MAX(CASE WHEN  RN = 1 THEN Code ELSE NULL END) code1,
MAX(CASE WHEN  RN = 2 THEN Code ELSE NULL END) code2,
MAX(CASE WHEN  RN = 3 THEN Code ELSE NULL END) code3
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY unit_id ORDER BY Code) RN
    -- Here row number will generate for default ascending order over value from column "Code"
    FROM your_table
)A
GROUP BY unit_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 (or later) here is an alternative solution based on xml and `string_agg`:

```
declare @tmp table (unit_id int ,Code varchar(50))

insert into @tmp
values 
  (214825,'d1821')
 ,(214825,'d0235')
 ,(214825,'d0710')

;with splitted
as (
    select unit_id
        ,cast('<x>' + REPLACE(string_agg(Code,'_'), '_', '</x><x>') + '</x>' as xml) as Parts
    from @tmp
    group by unit_id
    )
select unit_id
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS code1      
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[2]', 'varchar(50)') AS code2
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[3]', 'varchar(50)') AS code3
from Splitted
```

Result:

[image]